# Disable tmux resizing using shift (only) + hjkl

Tags: resize, tmux

I added tmux binding for resizing pane like this

```
bind h select-pane -L
bind j select-pane -D
bind k select-pane -U
bind l select-pane -R
```

but ended up can't type HJKL (uppercase), since it's already resizing the panel. what I want to expect is using `ctrl-a` (prefix) then HJKL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tmux list-keys` to verify if those keys are actually sit in `prefix` key table. You may need to explicitly reset the prefix key via `set -g prefix C-a`.

Comment: I see.. I got this
`bind-key    -T root         H                 resize-pane -L 5`
`bind-key    -T root         J                 resize-pane -D 5`
`bind-key    -T root         K                 resize-pane -U 5`
`bind-key    -T root         L                 resize-pane -R 5`

but how do I know from which config this is loaded ? since in my `~/.tmux.conf` there's no root binding

Comment: @RifkiFauzi These kind of tasks can be done using `strace`. Try `strace tmux | grep open` and see what files are opened.

Comment: unfortunately there's no `strace` in osx.. I try `dtruss` but got an error message. I try to unbind the HJKL in my tmux.conf but still not work. is there any other way to unbind those keys ?

Comment: `unbind H`
`unbind J`
`unbind K`
`unbind L`

Comment: try unbinding them in root table. `unbind -T root H`